# QWT library installation problem on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake, qwt

I installed qt creator and mingw on Windows 10. Everthing is working but I have problem to compile qwt library (https://qwt.sourceforge.io/). Qt and compilator is installed on disk F:/Qt.

```
Start->Qt->mingw console

F:\qwt-6.1.5>qmake qwt.pro
Info: creating stash file F:\qwt-6.1.5\.qmake.stash

F:\qwt-6.1.5>mingw32-make
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || F:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_64/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile F:/qwt-6.1.5/src/src.pro ) && mingw32-make -f Makefile
      0 [main] sh 8736 sync_with_child: child 9992(0x1D8) died before initialization with status code 0xC0000142
    179 [main] sh 8736 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/usr/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:53: sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 128
```

```
F:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_32>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=F:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I would try running the different commands in the command line `cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || F:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_64/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile F:/qwt-6.1.5/src/src.pro ) && mingw32-make -f Makefile` individually. See which one is failing (if any).

Comment: ```mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'f:/qwt-6.1.5/src'
compiling qwt_abstract_scale_draw.cpp
      0 [main] sh 11536 sync_with_child: child 6160(0x1EC) died before initialization with status code 0xC0000142
    221 [main] sh 11536 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/usr/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:3550: release/qwt_abstract_scale_draw.o] Error 128
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'f:/qwt-6.1.5/src'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:49: release-all] Error 2```

Comment: I added Windows enivorment variables (PATH):
F:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_32\bin
F:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin

Looks like a problem with the path?

Comment: One suggestion (from the internet) is that this is caused by a program `sh.exe` you have somewhere which is different from the one that ming32-make is trying to run. So yes, it's a path error, you need to make sure that the mingw32 `sh` command is the one being picked up from your path.

Comment: Solution: mingw32-make SHELL=cmd, but after compiling:
```compiling qwt_dial_needle.cpp
compiling qwt_knob.cpp
compiling qwt_slider.cpp
compiling qwt_thermo.cpp
compiling qwt_wheel.cpp
generating moc/moc_predefs.h
moc qwt_dyngrid_layout.h
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:651: moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'f:/qwt-6.1.5/src'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:49: release-all] Error 2```

I have too many microprocessor compilers and they probably have problems with PATH.

Comment: ```
Setting up environment for Qt usage...

F:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_32>where sh.exe
C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\sh.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe

F:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_32>
```
You're right. But how now to redirect this path correctly to sh from mingw?

Answer (score 0):

In QT 5.15.0 some directory is changed and if you want to build qwt with qt 5.15.0 you need to modify the qwt source code, I added this code in file  qwt_global.h and it works at MVCS 2019 and qwt 6.1.4

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 15, 0)
#include <QtGui/QPainterPath>
#endif
```

Also, use qwt version >= 6.1.5 to pass this problem